# DB2 connection from C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, web-services, db2

I'm working on connecting to DB2 database from .NET (C#) using the .NET Service Provider `IBM.DATA.DB2.dll` (application is a web service which gets details from DB2 database). I have installed DB2 Runtime Client and configured the ODBC and the connection was successful.

When I try to open a DB2 Connection object in the .NET code, I get an error could not find `DB2APP.dll`. The dll is available in the DB2 Runtime Client Install Path, but it searches in the bin folder. (I copied it to local machine though it is not right) and it required a new file db2nmp.xml which is also available in runtime client install path but the application is looking under "**/WebService ProjectFolder/msg/en_US/db2nmp.xml**". I copied that one also and I'm able to connect to DB2. (I clearly think it is not right)

My question is how to force .NET to look in the DB2 Runtime Client install folder instead of searching in the web service project folder? I have tried all possible ways but still could not find an answer. Please help !!!!!

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908, although I have to say: why don't you include those files into your project? If for some reason the application path of the db2 client changes (e.g. a re-install) you'll have a problem.

Comment: Hi @Stefan , thanks for your response. I think we need not provide it in the runtime binding in config. I have seen the source code of other applications that we use that connect to DB2 database they have not it the runtime binding. they have added only reference to IBM.DATA.DB2.dll.

Comment: There is also an option "Copy local" on the property pages of the reference. If you set this to "true" it will be copied to the output folder. If you don't want that, Carlos's suggestion is quite nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We work with DB2, and the ISeries installation register the IDM.DATA.DB2 assemblies in the GAC. ([Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx)).

If you go to `c:\windows\assembly` you will see the registered assemblies and you should have them like this:

[image]

Using the  `IBM2.Data.Db2.Iseries` reference should be enough to perform database jobs.
It should find **whatever reference needed** registered in GAC.

Comment: Hi Carlos Landeras and @Stefan thanks for your response. The issue is now fixed. Here is the list of things I did which I think fixed the issue. 
i)First Added the inbuilt ASPNET service account (IIS Account) to the DB2USERS and DB2ADMNS group
ii)Secondly , I reinstalled the DB2 Runtime Client.[I installed it manually, instead of the installing it through software portal. (We have a portal in which we can request a software and it gets installed automatically)].
Thanks !

Comment: Im glad you finally fixed it @ArunG ;)